# Execution failed for task dexBuilderForDebug

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, ioexception, corruption

I’ve got big nasty error message recently when trying to build app. This happened after Windows crash (Insider build, ha ha).

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable
```

Here is full Gradle console output: https://pastebin.com/ri58vYN7

What I already tried:

- Delete /.gradle directory
- Delete app/build directory
- Invalidate caches / restart
- Clean project, rebuild project

What can I do about it? Is the only way to start new project?

Answer (score 0):

The crash should be a good sign for you to start learning and using a version control like git and start using Linux.

Usually, after Windows crash, one or more of your files in your project got corrupted. Sometimes the file becomes blank or contains cryptic text which the Gradle can't read and process. You need to check each file inside your project and fix it.

You must cherish the problems because it happens when you starting a new project. Start using version control or you will lost your precious time and project when Windows crash again.

Afaik, crash is a feature of Windows.

Comment: I'm already using git, but never had a chance to revert changes :) Also, that's good suggestion to use Linux. Which one do you recommend for development? Ubuntu? Where can I check availability of apps which I'm using on windows and can you send good guide on setting up Linux development environment? Thanks.

Comment: @Neone: Commonly, you can use Ubuntu for Android Development or you can try using [Devuan](https://devuan.org/). But if stability is your main concerns, you can try [Slackware](http://www.slackware.com/) (Btw, I'm a slackware user since 2011), though the learning curve is too steep. Probably you better to use [Devuan](https://devuan.org/), my co-worke using it now for about  4 month where he previously using Windows.

Comment: **UPDATE**



After a day of pain, gone back on Windows. Ubuntu Linux didn’t work with displayLink and froze on virtualization with emulator…I found corrupted directory at C:/Users/------/.android/build-cache 
I cannot delete it, but I will try to work it out with disk checking. I also deleted all other Android Studio files.